# how to know if url change is caused by BACK/FORWARD?

Tags: angular

I am listening to queryParams change with the following code:

```
activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe((params)=>{
  // do the thing
})
```

This doesn't differentiate between user updating the navigation URL by performing some action on the page (via  angular router) from user clicking BACK/FORWARD button in the browser.

In my case, if the user causes url change via action on the page, i display "APPLY CHANGES", change url and show selected filters. The data for filters is fetched from url. Data is fetched only after "APPLY CHANGES" is clicked. On the other hand, if the user clicked BACK or FORWARD, then displaying filters along with fetching of data is performed and "APPLY CHANGES" is never shown.

Is it possible to differentiate between these two situations? What api should be used?

Comment: You can't... there's the `popstate` event which would detect changes in the browser history stack... but even if you could, why would your query parameter handling care at all whether a navigation is back, forward, entered manually in the URL or through a link?

Comment: @Jcl subscribing to url changes allows me to display page according to current url string. I added an edit describing why knowing the origin of url change is important. queryParamMap does not care, that's why I am asking for the api that "does care"

Comment: In general, depending on the browser usage for the handling of your application is a bad and risky thing... in the latest years, for security (and good) reasons, your knowledge of the browser inside the pages has been blocked more and more, so even if there was an API for it, you'd probably lose access to it in the future

Comment: @Jcl Thanks, ` @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event) {
    console.log('Back or forward button pressed');
  }` did the trick